# Need Text from Website in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have a question about implementing external websites into a Google Chrome Extension.

The external website sets a Cookie and looks if a hash and the cookie have the same value.
If hash = cookie the page returns a "1"

My question:

Is there a possibility

1. to call up the check
2. to read this "result"

via background-page or script.

I didn't found anything at Google Chrome Extension (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

- Check Cookie ([Cookie API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html))
- Verify Hash ([Inspect URL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html))
- Perform Check ( [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) or [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html))
- and read result of Page using Chrome extensions ([Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) or [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)).